# SpringBoot OpenAPI Swagger rendering

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have a SpringBoot application where in I want to generate the Open API doc for the rest endpoint using Swagger. All the fields are generating fine except for the List of Beans which are rendering as String but I would like them in JSON format for the orderItems field. Please find the code and the screenshots below for reference. Requesting help.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.12</version>
</dependency>


@JsonProperty(value = "orderItems")
@ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(description = "item nos of the request", implementation = OrderItem.class, example = "[{itemId:1001, itemName:iphoneX, quantity:2}, {itemId:1002, itemName:ipad, quantity:2}]"))
@NotEmpty(message = "Order Items cannot be empty") 
private List<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
```

**Rendered**

[image]

**Preferred**
[image]